# Sum of arithmetic-geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation

I'm looking for a function that generates the sum of the products of the $i$-terms of a geometric and arithmetic progressions. In other words, I'm searching a closed form for the expression: $$\Omega_n=\tau_0+\tau_1+\tau_2+\cdots+\tau_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\tau_i=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\phi_i\cdot\Phi_i$$

where $\phi$ is an arithmetic progression: $$\phi_i = \mu_{\phi}+\delta_{\phi}\cdot i$$
and $\Phi$ is a geometric progression: $$\Phi_i=\mu_{\Phi}\cdot\delta_{\Phi}^i$$

So far, I've done those steps:

-Rewrite the summations as: $$\Omega_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mu_{\phi}+\delta_{\phi}\cdot i)(\mu_{\Phi}\cdot\delta_{\Phi}^i)$$

-Now, multiply in the two brackets, obtaining:
$$\Omega_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mu_{\phi}\cdot\mu_{\Phi}\cdot\delta_\Phi ^ i+\delta_\phi\cdot i \cdot\mu_\Phi\cdot\delta_\Phi^i$$

-I can split the four terms into two different sums:$$\Omega_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mu_{\phi}\cdot\mu_{\Phi}\cdot\delta_\Phi ^ i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_\phi\cdot i \cdot\mu_\Phi\cdot\delta_\Phi^i$$

-Being $\mu_\phi,\mu_\Phi,\delta_\Phi,\delta_\phi$ constants, we have: $$\Omega_n=\mu_{\phi}\cdot\mu_{\Phi}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\delta_\Phi ^ i+\delta_\phi\cdot\mu_\Phi\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i \cdot\delta_\Phi^i$$

-Let $\Omega_n=\rho_{1,n-1}+\rho_{2,n-1}$

-The first term is a geometric progression, so: $$\rho_{1,n-1}=\mu_{\phi}\cdot\mu_{\Phi}\cdot\frac{1-\delta_\Phi^{n-1}}{1-\delta_\Phi}=\cdot\mu_{\phi}\cdot\mu_{\Phi}\cdot\frac{\delta_\Phi^{n-1}-1}{\delta_\Phi-1}$$

-The second term is again the product of two variable quantities,so here I'm stuck. Any idea of how to move forward?

Thanks.

Comment: The $(-1)$ that you added in the last equation should not be there.

Comment: Yes, sorry. My mistake.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Isn't this a telescopic series

Comment: @PythonSage: no, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, what we need to evaluate here is a sum of the form $S = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx^k$.  That is, I will take $x = \delta_{\Phi}$ and use $k$ as my index of summation; the term added for $i=0$ is $0$, so we can leave it out.

Consider the function $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx^{k-1}$ (which is $S/x$).  We note that
$$
\int_{0}^t f(x)\,dx = \int_0^t \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx^{k-1}\right)\,dx  = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_0^t kx^{k-1} \,dx = 
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}t^k.
$$
Using the formula for the sum of a geometric progression, we have
$$
\int_{0}^t f(x)\,dx = t\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}t^{k-1} = t \frac{t^{n}-1}{t-1} = \frac{t^{n+1} - t}{t-1}.
$$
Taking the derivative of both sides, we have
$$
f(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\left[ \frac{t^k - t}{t-1} \right] = 
\frac{nt^{n+1} - (n+1)t^n + 1}{(t-1)^2}.
$$
So, we finally have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx^k = xf(x) = x \cdot \frac{nx^{n+1} - (n+1)x^n + 1}{(x-1)^2}.
$$

Comment: Is there a method to reach this formula without using integtals?

Comment: One approach comes to mind, but it would require that we use infinite series. Also, now that you have a formula you could prove it by induction.

Comment: @Matteo there's also a [proof on this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#Sum_of_the_terms) that just uses algebra. Also, it gives you the formula that you were looking for in the first place.